# equation missing } error

Tags: equations, errors

I got missing `}` error for this code. I tried deleting the `$` sign, but it did not work. Could anybody help, please?

```
\begin{equation}\label{5eq}
 D_{i}{}^{+}=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{m}{W_{j}(a_{ij}{}^{+}$\minus$ a_{ij})^{2}}}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you input `\minus`? Put differently, why aren't you inputing `-`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please replace `\minus` with `-` and get rid of the `$` math-mode initiators/terminators.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{5eq}
 D_{i}^{+}=\sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^m W_{j}(a_{ij}^{+} - a_{ij})^2 }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.